# Trying to create defect using Rally .net REST API and unable to set Owner

Tags: rally

Below is the piece of code I have tried, I am able to set Project value but not owner.

```
var restAPI = new RallyRestApi("abc@xyz.com", "1234");

String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12345678901";
String projectRef = "/project/9876543210";

DynamicJsonObject toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();

 //Pass Project
 toCreate["Project"] = projectRef;


 //Pass Owner
 DynamicJsonObject myUser = restAPI.GetCurrentUser();
 string myUserRef = myUser["_ref"];

 toCreate["Owner"] = myUserRef;


 CreateResult createResult = restAPI.Create(workspaceRef, "defect", toCreate);

Alternately I have tried below to set Owner, even this did not work for me. 

String userRef = "/user/11123456225";
toCreate["Owner"] = userRef;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Include more details explaining the result and the expected result. Please refer help section for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested [this code](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/rally-dot-net-rest-apps/blob/master/createUpdateDefect.cs) that sets owner on a defect successfully:

```
 {
            RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi("user@co.com", "secret", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "v2.0");
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/11111"; //use valid workspace OID in your Rally
            String projectRef = "/project/12345";         //use valid project OID in your Rally
            String userRef = "/user/777";
            DynamicJsonObject d = new DynamicJsonObject();
            d["Name"] = "some bug";
            d["Project"] = projectRef;
            d["Owner"] = userRef;

            CreateResult createResult = restApi.Create(workspaceRef, "Defect", d);
            DynamicJsonObject defect = restApi.GetByReference(createResult.Reference, "FormattedID");
            Console.WriteLine(defect["FormattedID"]);

            //update defect
            defect["Description"] = "bad bug";
            OperationResult updateResult = restApi.Update(defect["_ref"], defect);
        }
```

What does "unable to set" mean: do you get  an error message, or it fails silently while setting other fields?

Comment: It fails silently while setting other fields. I realized now that I did not set valid workspace. It is working now.